# experiencing issue with using texreg in R markdown

Tags: r, macos, markdown, knitr, texreg

I'm experiencing issue with using texreg in R markdown to produce PDF. 
I'm not sure if it's the new OSX or something about my set up. (I'm new to MAC and relatively new to R.)

So far...

- I cannot run my old latex files.
- I can run the old latex files if I rewrite them in a slightly different syntex (for example take out the \ )
- I can run markdown files without texreg.
- If I run markdown
  with texreg in it, I get an error saying that pandoc cannot convert
  the files. Here is the error:

! Misplaced \noalign.

```
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.114 ...sh{}begin\{tabular\}\{l c c c c \} \hline
```

> pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
>
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In Ops.factor(left, right) : '<' not meaningful for factors
>   Execution halted

- When I put in texreg function, the closest I have gotten is that it print out the latex code in the pdf.

I'm on OSX EL CAPITAN, newest version of R, MACTEX, PANDOC.
I think knitr, mactex are installed correctly since I can produce pdf from both markdown and latex. Comments?
So may be the problem is pandoc?

I did read a post about some issue with OSX EL CAPITAN and MACTEX but it should be fixed.

Comment: You'll need to provide the LaTeX code that's causing the issue...

Comment: **minimal** code that causes an issue, ideally.